# Input not being read using certain literals

Tags: c++, string, cin

Very new programmer with a seemingly obscure problem:

```
string currency = "???";
double amount = 0.0;
double amount_final = 0.0;
cin >> amount >> currency;
if (currency == "GBP"){
amount_final = amount*1.47;
}
 else if (currency == "Yen"){
    amount_final = amount*0.0083;
}
else if(currency == "Euro"){
    amount_final = amount*1.07;
```

Everything works fine except if you enter "Euro" in which case it acts like you didn't enter anything and returns the initial values.
A little bit of testing showed me that the only time I run into problems is if the first letter of the string is E or e and isn't preceded by a whitespace, any other value I tried works fine.

TL;DR: If I change nothing except "Euro" to "Fish" the program works, what's up?

Comment: [localhost functionTest]$ ./a.out 
11 GBP
16.17
[localhost functionTest]$ ./a.out 
11 Yen
0.0913
[localhost functionTest]$ ./a.out 
11 Euro
11.77

Comment: You will understand once you ponder about why this input yields a float: ``1E-3``. The E from the Euro is parsed as being part of a floating point number. The exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The float parser is greedy and consumes the "E" which stands for exponent from the input stream, leaving "uro" as the remainder of the input stream.

Basically the greedy parsing fails here as it is a grammar which would require a lookahead of 1. ("E" followed by number).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers to you both, so basically e is reserved for some other function and doesn't want to be used next to numbers? :P

Comment: *The float parser is greedy.* +1.

Comment: No E is not reserved per se. This is why the other answer uses a whitespace between the number and the currency to get it working. Then the float parser stops at the white space and is happy without the E. To work around for this to work also without whitespace would require you to create a real float-currency-parser. For example by means of getting a regular expression to work.

Comment: Alright, thanks very much. Was kind of bugging me for OCD reasons. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string currency = "???";
    double amount = 0.0;
    double amount_final = 0.0;
    std::cin >> amount >> currency;
    if (currency == "GBP"){
    amount_final = amount*1.47;
    }
    else if (currency == "Yen"){
        amount_final = amount*0.0083;
    }
    else if(currency == "Euro"){
        amount_final = amount*1.07;
    }
    std::cout << amount_final << std::endl;
}

[localhost functionTest]$ ./a.out 
11 GBP
16.17

[localhost functionTest]$ ./a.out 
11 Yen
0.0913

[localhost functionTest]$ ./a.out 
11 Euro
11.77
```

Sorry in my case is working, are you always using Amount Currency ?

Comment: Because you have a whitespace between the number and the Euro word.

Comment: Becuase you have to write it in order to make the cin operator to work as spected. If you don't put the space(\n or similar, some kind of delim) then there is no way to make it work properly :-).

Comment: You trickster! ;) Yes the bottom line is that the parser for float greedily sucks in the E, leaving "uro" as the currency.